# Does Arch linux have a main repository?

Tags: arch-linux, repository

I've noticed that there are a lot of mirrors out there for arch linux, but I was wondering if Arch has it's own repo like [ubuntu](http://archive.ubuntu.com/). I've been searching the web, using terms like arch repo, arch main repo, etc. and I keep getting things like the [package list](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/), [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/), and the wiki about the [Official](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/official_repositories) and [Unofficial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/unofficial_user_repositories) Repository's.

So my question is this;

- Does archlinux.org have it's own repository?
- Is the [package list](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/) the repo? If so, how do I add that to
  pacman.conf to use it?
- Also, where do the maintainers upload packages for all the mirrors to grab
  them? I would assume they use a 'main' repository.

Any help/information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research, I've learned that Arch Linux does have a main mirror, however, base on [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DeveloperWiki:NewMirrors#2-tier_mirroring_scheme) article, because of their bandwidth limit, they only allow certain mirrors to pull from there main repo.

As for where to upload packages, you need to send it to the Arch Linux mailing list to be reviewed as explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_submission_guidelines).